# C++, a table of functions, and templates

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++14, c++17

I have a table of functions.  It looks something like this:

```
struct AnimalFunction {
    void (*Walk)(int a);
    void (*Sing)(int a, int b);
    void (*Dance)(int a, int b, int c);
};
using AnimalFunctionTable = map<string, AnimalFunction>;
```

In other words, I have rows of `AnimalFunction`'s and a map from some string that I know to, essentially, a type.  For simplicity, maybe I include some extra arguments so that they all have the same signature and just ignore what they don't need : `WalkDog(int a, int, int) { ... }`.

Now I have to define functions like `WalkDog()`, `SingDog()`, `DanceDog()`, and then `WalkGiraffe()` and `SingGiraffe()` (but our giraffes don't dance, so they get some default function that maybe I have to name at least).

My goal is simplicity of maintenance.  I'd like to write some template functions like

```
template<typename AnimalT>
void WalkAnimal(int a) { ... }
```

so that the table can just be a mapping of the string to the type.  (Sometimes I can write such a general function, sometimes I need to write a specialised one, but at least I'm getting the compiler to maintain my table.)  But I'm not convinced that C++ (14 in my case, though this could be an argument to upgrade to 17) supports such a thing.

The reason this starts with a string is because of an API accessible on a network.  Other clients can't be expected to talk the same C++ types as my system, so they tell me something like `{action: "walk", animal: "dog"}`.  (It's a protobuf, not JSON, but this question is text.)

```
// What I want to say, in my dreams:
actions[action_string][animal_string](arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

though the precise operators aren't important, just an illustration here.

Any suggestions, other than writing the entire table explicitly?

Comment: Surely I'm just dense, but I don't get how your sample function template fits in your design. Could you maybe expand on what it should do?

Comment: @Quentin See Jarod42's response below.  Probably my bad phrasing, but he managed to see through it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand, you want to replace:

```cpp
struct AnimalFunction {
    void (*Walk)(int a);
    void (*Sing)(int a, int b);
    void (*Dance)(int a, int b, int c);
};

void WalkDog(int a) {/*..*/}
void SingDog(int a, int b) {/*..*/}
void DanceDog(int a, int b, int c) {/*..*/}

void WalkGiraffe(int a) {/*..*/}
void SingGiraffe(int a, int b) {/*..*/}

std::map<std::string, AnimalFunction> animalFunctions = {
  {"Dog", {&WalkDog, &SingDog, &DanceDog}},
  {"Giraffe", {&WalkGiraffe, &SingGiraffe, nullptr}},
};
```

by something like:

```cpp
struct AnimalFunction {
    void (*Walk)(int a);
    void (*Sing)(int a, int b);
    void (*Dance)(int a, int b, int c);
};

struct Dog {/*..*/};
struct Giraffe {/*..*/};

template <typename T> void WalkT(int a) {/*..*/}
template <typename T> void SingT(int a, int b) {/*..*/}
template <typename T> void DanceT(int a, int b, int c) {/*..*/}

template <> void DanceT<Giraffe>(int a, int b, int c) {/*Empty*/}
// ...

template <typename T>
AnimalFunction MakeAnimalFunction()
{
    return {&WalkT<T>, &SingT<T>, &DanceT<T>};
}

std::map<std::string, AnimalFunction> animalFunctions = {
  {"Dog", MakeAnimalFunction<Dog>()},
  {"Giraffe", MakeAnimalFunction<Giraffe>()},
};
```

Comment: Perfect, I hadn't thought of something so simple as a factory function.  That sorts it perfectly, thanks!